# What is a Primitive Atomic Formula?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, predicate-logic

I am reading "Axiomatic Set Theory" by Patrick Suppes and he defines a primitive atomic formula as follows:

A primitive atomic is an expression of the form ($v\in w$ ), or of the form ($v=w$) where v and w are either general variables or constant '0'(empty set).

My question is what is a primitive atomic formula? Is it a statement of predicate logic that has a clear meaning that makes sense in the language? Come to think of it, if it doesn't take too long to explain whats a primitive formula?

Comment: Atomic formulae consist of a basic predicate symbol of the language and the appropriate number of terms. It has no bearing on the natural language interpretability of the predicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a standard first-order language an atomic formula is just an $n$-place predicate (from the stock of $n$-place predicates in the language's basic vocabulary) followed by $n$ terms. A term is whatever you can form from the function-expressions, names and variables of the language in the usual way explained in any logic text.

The primitive language of axiomatic set theory (unaugmented by the introduction of additional defined expressions) is exceptionally sparse. There are at most two built-in predicates, '$\in$' and '$=$' (see Carl Mummert's comment). And since there are no constants in the language, and no buiit-in function expressions either (remember, we are talking about the initial unaugmented language), the only terms are variables. So the only atomic formulae are the likes of '$\in vw$' and  '$= vw$', conventionally re-written  '$v \in w$' and  '$v=w$'.

Finally, talk of primitive atomic formulae here just highlights that we are talking of atomic formulae of the basic, unaugmented, primitive (call it what you will) language.

Comment: I don't have Suppes's book to hand so I didn't comment before. "Primitive atomic formula" sounds like a confusing pleonasm to me and not just a stylistic variation.  It clearly confused the OP. Why would anyone write "primitive atomic formula"?

Comment: @Rob Arthan: I believe that Suppes builds from "primitive atomic formulas" to "primitive formulas", which are formulas in the language of set theory (well, with equality included). Then "formulas" in general may include definitional extensions - but in principle of course these can be restated as "primitive" formulas using only the language of set theory.

Comment: Regarding the answer, I wanted to point out that in more classical presentations the "language of set theory" includes only membership, not equality, which can be defined from membership. It seems to be a relatively modern change to include equality in the basic language for set theory.

Comment: @CarlMummert Yes indeed on both points!