# What is meant by "string of symbols of the form..." here?

Tags: logic

I was reading a text on introductory set theory and came across this:

[image]

Now, my question is whether the writer means that a string of symbols is of the form $(\in{v_i}{v_j}) or....$ or whether a symbol is actually of that form because I think the latter is true.

Comment: Is this from page 11 of http://www.math.toronto.edu/weiss/set_theory.pdf? Just before the lines you copied, the author described what the form of a symbol can be.

Comment: Yes it is. Sorry, But does that then mean that the form he gives is the form for a string of symbols?

Comment: Also relevant, I think: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1390191/what-is-a-primitive-atomic-formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The language of *first-order* set theory is "made" of :

> (individual) *variables* : $v_1, v_2, \ldots$
>
> the logical *connectives* ; $\lnot, \to, \lor, \land$
>
> the *quantifiers* : $\forall, \exists$
>
> the *equality* symbol : $=$

and :

> the binary *predicate* letter : $\in$.

Thus, the only way to form atomic formulae is to use the two binary predicates : $=$ and $\in$.

Thus, an *atomic* formula can be one of :

> > $v_1=v_2, v_1 \in v_2, \ldots$.

A formula like : $(v_1=v_2) \lor (v_1 \in v_2)$ is not *atomic*, because it contains a connective.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification but I was just wondering whether these individual variables are propositional or ordinary?

Comment: @ReinhildVanRosenú - no; set theory is based on first-order logic; thus, the variables "range" over "objects" (i.e. sets) and not propositions.

Answer (score 3):

On page 11 of http://www.math.toronto.edu/weiss/set_theory.pdf, I believe what the author means is that
$$(v_i \in v_j)$$
is an atomic formula, and
$$(v_i = v_j)$$
also is an atomic formula.

For an example, look at the top of page 15.
$$((∀v_1)((v_1 = v_2) → (v_1 ∈ v_0)) ∧ (∃v_2)(v_2 ∈ v_1))$$
is a formula containing three atomic formulas, $(v_1 = v_2)$, $(v_1 ∈ v_0)$ and $(v_2 ∈ v_1)$, along with other symbols as allowed by the several rules of creating formulas on pages 11 and 12.

---

It may be worth noting that although the title of the document is
"An Introduction to Set Theory", it is actually a set of course notes
for a *graduate course,* so it is "introductory" only with respect to to an advanced level of mathematics. 
I suppose the audience is supposed to have some familiarity
already with the formulas of set theory.

Comment: Yes, I acknowledge that it is for a graduate course and I myself would not take it up but is the only choice I have (too complicated to explain here) and I can reasonably understand it since I'm familiar with formal logic, though not greatly.

Comment: I'm not saying you can't use the book. It will just take more effort per page than an undergraduate treatment. The nice thing nowadays is you have stackexchange to help you past the parts where the author expects too much too quickly for you.

Comment: Just of interest, would you advise someone to be fully comfortable or at least reasonably comfortable with first-order and propositional logic (or any extra mathematical logic) before attempting to tackle and fully work with and understand set theory from an undergraduate perspective? Because I am only reasonably comfortable in understanding, application and intuition in propositional logic and no little to nothing regarding first-order logic. I would really appreciate your advice because I loath doing something, even if I have to, which I will not fully understand.

Comment: I'm probably not the best person to give advice on learning foundational mathematics--too little of it too long ago--but my _guess_ is that you can study first-order logic and use some of that to help with learning set theory, or you can learn set theory and (if needed) use some of that to help learn first-order logic later. In either case you start with some kind of list of allowed symbols and rules for combining them, and build upward from there. The notes you're using actually look quite good to me.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think I might start with first order logic since some of the definitions, such as a "variable" (predicate), seem to obscure for me in this context.

Answer (score 1):

Properly and carefully written, there would be some sort of quoting convention that is used to distinguish sequences of logical symbols (the “object language”) from statements that the author is making about those sequences (the “metalanguage”).  Typically the sequences of logical symbols are placed in quotes, so that one says for example:

> The symbol “$\&$” denotes logical conjunction.

Such a sentence is entirely in the metalanguage, because the notation

> “$\&$”

is taken to be not the logical conjunction sign itself, but rather the metalanguage's *name* for the logical conjunction sign. There are other conventions to indicate the same thing: sequences of symbols in the object language are sometimes set on a monospaced font, or indented and centered.  (Or indented and highlighted, as I did just above.)  Your source does not use any convention consistently.  But more serious writers are sometimes more careful.

None of the conventions works perfectly in this case, because

> The *atomic formulas* are strings of symbols of the form “$v_i \in v_j$” or “$v_i = v_j$“

is actually incorrect, because the $i$ and $j$ are symbols of the metalanguage, not the object language.  One can say instead something like:

> If $v_i$ and $v_j$ are variables of the object language, then the strings obtained by concatenating the three symbols $v_i$, “$\in$” or “$=$”, and $v_j$ are called *atomic formulas*.

Note that we don't quote $v_i$ or $v_j$ here: they are not object language variable symbols, but metalanguage names for unspecified object language variable symbols.  Again the entire sentence is in the metalanguage, and there is no ambiguity about what “or” means: it is the metalanguage (English) word “or”.  In particular it has nothing to do with the object language symbol “$\lor$”; if it were, it would be written as

> “$\lor$”

and not as

> or

The reason this kind of pattern is rarely followed is that it is circuitous, verbose, and confusing.  A simpler but still correct method is to use the “quasiquotation” notation, invented by W.V.O. Quine, in which the sentence above would look like this:

> If $\Phi$ and $\Psi$ are variable symbols, then the formulas $⌜\Phi\in\Psi⌝$ and $⌜\Phi=\Psi⌝$ are called *atomic formulas*.

Here something like

> $⌜\Phi=\Psi⌝$

has been defined to mean the same as

> the result of concatenating the formula $\Phi$, the symbol “=”, and the formula $\Psi$.

Note that “$\Phi$” in the previous example is a name in the metalanguage, which is defined to represent a formula in the object language, and analogously

> “=”

is the name of the “=” symbol, so again the previous example is written entirely in the metalanguage.

For fuller details see [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-quotation).